# $.post always returns undefine

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

When I make the following jQuery call

```
$.post('/publish/comments', 
  parms,
  function(data, textStatus){
    console.log('textStatus: ' . textStatus);
    console.log('returned data: ' . data);
    console.log('nextPage: ' . data.nextPage);
  },
  "json"
);
```

the console shows that data, textStatus, and data.nextPage are all undefined.

But in the Chrome dev tools (network tab) I can see that the following JSON data is being pass back from the server.

```
{success:true, nextPage: /go/page/requestId/182/src/publish}
nextPage: "/go/page/requestId/182/src/send"
success: true
```

Thoughts?

Comment: String concatenation in JS is `+`, not `.`. PHP uses `.` for string concatenation, but in JS `.` is used to access the property of an object. Or what do think `'nextPage: ' . data.nextPage` would do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Felix pointed out concats need "+"

Also, I have found that if you want to log an entire object, you don't want to include strings inside your console.log().

Try `console.log(data)` instead of putting strings before it (like "data: ") this will guarantee that the whole object can be seen in the console.

Answer (score 3):

you need to concat using `+` operator not the `.` as used in php

```
$.post('/publish/comments', 
       parms,
       function(data, textStatus){
                            console.log('textStatus: ' + textStatus);
                            console.log('returned data: '+ data);
                            console.log('nextPage: ' + data.nextPage);    
       },
       "json"
       );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code pattern to log to the console:

```
console.log(['textStatus', textStatus]);
```

This allows to print a message and an object to the console.

That said, `'textStatus: ' . textStatus` is `undefined` because JavaScript strings don't have a property `textStatus` (`.` is the "access property" operator not the PHP concat operator)